# How do I check to see if an apt lock file is locked?

Tags: apt, aptitude, dpkg

I am writing a script to do some `apt` commands, but I am running into potential issues of the `apt/dpkg` databases being locked so my script bails.  I want to check the lock files (i.e. `/var/lib/dpkg/lock`) before doing anything just like `apt` does when it runs its command, but I can't figure out how `apt` is performing the lock.

The lock file is always there, and `apt-get` is not doing a flock on the file.  How else would it be checking to see if it is in use?  From an `strace` I see that `apt-get` opens the file, but that is it.  In my script, I can open the file while `apt-get` has it open as well.

Comment: Why can't you just catch the error and return an understandable error code before bailing? You didn't say what language you are using, but all script languages that I know of would let you do this, including ksh, Ruby, Perl and almost certainly Python as well.

Comment: Let me add: the scripting languages (Perl, Ruby, Python) should also have function libraries to interface with APT: could those help?

Comment: I'm using ruby, but come to find out ruby doesn't fully implement fcntl.  I'd rather look for the lock the same way as apt instead of wasting time to let apt start and fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that apt is using a fcntl.  Since I am using Ruby for the scripting language, I had to create my own function to look for lock.  The reason for this, is because Ruby does not implement the fcntl function entirely.  It only provides the function call and constants.  The ability to build flock structs and how to pass them is left out or not documented.

Here is the [list](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/87589) I found talking about that.

Here is the function I ended up writing:

```
def flocked? &block
  flockstruct = [Fcntl::F_RDLCK, 0, 0, 0, 0].pack("ssqqi")
  fcntl Fcntl::F_GETLK, flockstruct
  status = flockstruct.unpack("ssqqi")[0]
  case status
    when Fcntl::F_UNLCK
      return false 
    when Fcntl::F_WRLCK|Fcntl::F_RDLCK
      return true
    else
      raise SystemCallError, status
  end
end
```

Comment: So to be clear, this method is intended to be monkey-patched onto the `File` class? It certainly doesn't work if you define it in the main context, as `fcntl` isn't a method there, and you haven't provided any mechanism for passing in the file to check. Also, what's the `&block` for? It's never called. Also, you left out the `require 'fcntl'`

Comment: Also, in my tests, this code only succeeds in testing for write locks. `Fcntl::F_WRLCK|Fcntl::F_RDLCK` is equivalent to `Fcntl::F_WRLCK`, since `Fcntl::F_RDLCK` is 0, and even aside from that, passing `Fcntl::F_RDLCK` in the `flockstruct` means that the system call will respond with `Fcntl::F_UNLCK` anyway unless the file is write-locked...

Answer (score 5):

Well I thought there would be a simple answer here but I can't find anything.  First, are you 100% sure that lock file is always there?  Try running

```
lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

as root to see if any process has it open.

From what I've read, apt-get does an fcntl lock, but I haven't looked at the code to verify. I guess that wuld explain why the file is there all the time, apt just locks it as needed.

What about just doing a check of the process list when your script runs, and exiting if apt is running at the same time?  Would that be sufficient for your use?

Looks like [this person](http://www.linux-archive.org/debian-dpkg/323765-cant-externally-acquire-lock-var-lib-apt-lists-lock.html) went down the same path as you did, without much success.

Comment: I thought of the lsof, but I wanted to use the same lock as apt.  I did find that the fcntl is how it is locking from an strace.

Answer (score 5):

I came here looking for a solution similar to what gondoi ended up using but written in Python instead of Ruby. The following seems to work well:

```python
import fcntl

def is_dpkg_active():
    """
    Check whether ``apt-get`` or ``dpkg`` is currently active.

    This works by checking whether the lock file ``/var/lib/dpkg/lock`` is
    locked by an ``apt-get`` or ``dpkg`` process, which in turn is done by
    momentarily trying to acquire the lock. This means that the current process
    needs to have sufficient privileges.

    :returns: ``True`` when the lock is already taken (``apt-get`` or ``dpkg``
              is running), ``False`` otherwise.
    :raises: :py:exc:`exceptions.IOError` if the required privileges are not
             available.

    .. note:: ``apt-get`` doesn't acquire this lock until it needs it, for
              example an ``apt-get update`` run consists of two phases (first
              fetching updated package lists and then updating the local
              package index) and only the second phase claims the lock (because
              the second phase writes the local package index which is also
              read from and written to by ``dpkg``).
    """
    with open('/var/lib/dpkg/lock', 'w') as handle:
        try:
            fcntl.lockf(handle, fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
            return False
        except IOError:
            return True
```

Answer (score 3):

From a shell script (see [flock(1)](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man1/flock.1.html)):

```
flock --timeout 60 --exclusive --close /var/lib/dpkg/lock apt-get -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" upgrade
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "Another process has f-locked /var/lib/dpkg/lock" 1>&2
  exit 1
fi
```